# unable to use python modules in airflow dag

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow and when I install a library, such as `boto3`, I just get an error on the Airflow server web ui. `Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/s3-dag.py] No module named 'boto3'`
. I've installed this lib using pip and the airflow tests work when I run them.

How can I configure airflow to allow me to use external modules like this?

Comment: are you sure that `boto3` module has been installed (and is available on `PYTHONPATH`) for all your `Celery` **workers** *(assuming you are using `CeleryExecutor`)*

Comment: I'm using a single node executor

Comment: I strongly believe that `boto3` is not on the `PYTHONPATH` of environment in which your tasks are running

Comment: I got it working, I had to mount requirements.txt to the docker volume and have a script to install the libs onto the path, thanks

Comment: Consider adding an answer of your own here for reference of others

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I had to mount requirements.txt to the docker volume and have a script to install the libs onto the path